# How do i divide a string or int in c# WinForms?

Tags: c#, string, winforms, integer, divide

I am trying to get a value of trackbar / slider, divide it by 100 and display the value in label.

I get an error Operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'string'.

Here's my try:

```cs
private void siticoneTrackBar1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    label6.Text = siticoneTrackBar1.Value / 100.ToString();
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Put parantheses arround your math expression and then call ToString on that.

Comment: You cannot divide an int by a string, try (value / 100).ToString(), so you cast the result to a string after the maths

Comment: `label6.Text = (siticoneTrackBar1.Value / 100).ToString();`

Comment: Also keep in mind _integer division_ is different than floating point division.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is operator precedence here: you're trying to divide the value of `siticoneTrackBar1.Value` by the result of calling `100.ToString()`. Instead, I strongly suspect you intended to perform the division of the two *numbers*, then call `ToString` on the *result*. The "dot" operator has higher precedence than division, so you need to use brackets to tell the compiler what to do:

```cs
private void siticoneTrackBar1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    label6.Text = (siticoneTrackBar1.Value / 100).ToString();
}
```